# How much of a performance impact is passing in a reference every frame?

Tags: c++, reference, draw, sfml

I'm using SFML, and in my main draw function, I'm passing in a reference to my `sf::RenderWindow` to various other draw functions (around 7-8).

My question is, how much of a performance impact is this? Would it be much better to store a reference to the window once in the various ctors which the respective draws use? In my head this way is my preferred approach, but I'm just looking for confirmation!

Many thanks!

Comment: As with all optimization questions you should try and profile, but passing an additional parameters to a handful of functions won't be anywhere near a measurable performance hit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Yes

passing something, even if just a reference, *has* a performance impact.

## But

*How much* is something you should measure. It's probably so small, that you cannot even measure it. It's negligible.

So use the way that makes your code more readable or better structured, because the better your code is in that regard, the less errors you will make. I will take an error free program with 119 fps any day over a bug-ridden 120 fps piece.

Comment: Great! Thanks for the answer. I'm relatively new to C++ so I wasn't sure how big of a performance hit it would be at 60 times/second.